# Octave Function Undefined

Tags: function, octave, octave-gui

Any idea why the following produces an error?

```
printf("this is my text\n");

MyFunc;

function MyFunc
  printf("printing from inside function\n");
endfunction
```

This is the error I get (from the Command Window)

*error: 'MyFunc' undefined near line 3, column 3
error: called from
function_example at line 3 column 1*

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I see the issue now.   The function definition needs to be placed before the function call is made - as shown below.

```
printf("this is my text\n");

function MyFunc
  printf("printing from inside function\n");
endfunction

MyFunc;
```

Comment: Correct. In particular, note that this is the opposite of matlab. Matlab expects 'inline' definitions at the end of a script. Therefore if you care at all about matlab compatibility you should probably avoid inline function definitions.